# How many Federation Starships did James T. Kirk destroy?

Tags: star-trek, federation

How many Federation Starships was James T. Kirk responsible for destroying?

Comment: Does that count ships destroyed by M5 while Kirk was Captain Dunsel?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Short answer**:  If you don't count M5's actions, or the class J cargo ship (since Harry Mudd should not have tried to flee), then he destroyed the *Constellation*, the *Reliant*, and the *Enterprise*.

**More details**:  During the series, he destroyed:

- The *Constellation* in *The Doomsday Machine* by ramming it down the throat of the planet killer and having it self destruct inside the machine
- In *Mudd's Women* he puts a tractor beam on Harry Mudd's ship, a class J cargo ship, and Mudd insists on trying to flee, so the ship falls apart.  (It could be easily argued that was not Kirk's fault.)

And in *The Ultimate Computer*, while the M5 was operating, one could say none of these were Kirk's responsibility, but he was technically still Captain of the *Enterprise*, so they would be considered his responsibility:

- The *Woden*, a freighter, which may not really be Federation property
- The *Excalibur* is crippled and all hands are killed by M5.  (It's not clear if, by crippled, it could still be towed back and fixed.)

He blamed himself for the death of half the crew of the *Farragut*, because he hesitated firing the ship's phasers, but he later learned that even if he had fired without hesitating, it would have made no difference.

In the movies he destroyed:

- The *Reliant* in *The Wrath of Kahn*
- The *Enterprise* (NCC-1701) in *The Search for Spock*

I'm not even getting into the animated series or non-canon (in other words, what's not on screen).  I've gone through an episode listing and reviewed plots for all the episodes and movies.  While it's possible I missed something, I think this is pretty complete.

Comment: Kirk also destroyed an unidentified Klingon cruiser after it attacked Enterprise near Organia in Season One Episode "Errand of Mercy."

Comment: @SteveWhite not a federation ship.

Comment: He disabled the Reliant. Khan destroyed it.

Comment: He killed Enterprise-A in The Ashes to Eden novel too

Comment: It sounds like the Klingons should be singing songs of Kirk.

Comment: @Rob I would say Kirk destroyed the Reliant. He shot it so badly the vessel would almost certainly have been decommissioned if Khan didn't finish off what was left of it.

Comment: @LincolnMan maybe... but he did try to get Khan to surrender it.